# Search string, get next value and write in xml field python

Tags: python, xml, search

I have this content in xml file

```
 <Document>
<CustomerCode></CustomerCode>
<CustomerWebLogin></CustomerWebLogin>
<CustomerName></CustomerName>
<CustomerAddress></CustomerAddress>
<Field Name="COMPANY1" FieldName="{VIS_COMPANY.DOCUMENTS}"><FormattedValue>Testing company</FormattedValue><Value>Testing company</Value></Field>'), (24, '<Field Name="UnboundString1" FieldName="{@UnboundString1}"><FormattedValue>0100 - ROME (RM)</FormattedValue></Field>
```

What I need is:
searching for `{VIS_COMPANY.DOCUMENTS}">`
get next value `Testing company` and finally write it in its related xml field `<CustomerName>Testin company</CustomerName>`

How can I do that?Tnx

Comment: [Edit] your Question and past the `XML` content exactly. It's important about the answer, to know if to deal with **valid** or **invalid** `XML` content.

Comment: Corrected, sorry

Comment: Start with [The ElementTree XML API - parsing-xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) and [finding-interesting-elements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements)

Comment: I don't want to use XML element tree, I just want to search a string near another and put that string into a certain line/field

Comment: *"don't want to use XML element tree"*: Feel free not to use the `xml` module. The `xml` module provide all function needed to do: *"search a string ... and put that string into a field "*. You can do it with [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) but it's far more complicated.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I don't need to search that string and get the value. I need to search and get _**near**_ value

Comment: *"and get near value"*: The `xml` module does also support this. You can [finding-interesting-elements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) within the matching `<Field ...{VIS_COMPANY.DOCUMENTS}` Element and get the `.text`, which is `'Testing company'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what I was looking for, using just RE lib:

**search text and get value near searchkey**

```
words = re.findall(r'\w+', contentwhereyouwanttosearchinside)
index = words.index('SEARCHKEY')
```

**print next 3 word e.g. near searchkey**

```
value1 = words[index + 1:index + 3] 
print(value1)
```